# Do a DB2 insert with a select and parameters

Tags: sql, jdbc, db2, spring-jdbc

I want to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLEA
(
 COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN 3
)
SELECT FOOBAR, DOOBAR, ?
FROM TABLEB
```

And then send this to JDBC via Spring JDBC to update...

```
simpleJdbcTemplate.update( mySqlFromAbove, someVariableToReplaceQuestionMark );
```

Is this even possible? It would work fine if I replace the question mark with the hardcoded value when building my SQL query, but I don't want to open myself to SQL injection...

**Edit -** 
I get 
*nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.SqlException: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -418, SQLSTATE: 42610, SQLERRMC: null* 
Which seems to indicate 
*Invalid use of a parameter marker ?*

Comment: We were getting the same error, and we fixed the problem by recycling the server. When in doubt, reboot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to type-cast your parameter marker so DB2 knows what to expect.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO TABLEA
(
 COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN 3
)
SELECT FOOBAR, DOOBAR, cast(? as int)
FROM TABLEB
```

Obviously, cast to the appropriate type -- int is just an example.

Comment: Solved 1 problem, made new problem

Comment: Worked if I did a specific cast.. like   cast(? as char(8)).. just as char wasn't enough

Answer (score 2):

Here's the [DB2 SQL Message Reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/r0002159.htm). Here's an extract of relevance for the SQLCODE and SQLSTATE you retrieved:

> ### SQL0418N
>
> A statement contains a use of a parameter marker that is not valid.
>
> #### Explanation:
>
> Untyped parameter markers cannot be used:
>
> - in a SELECT list
> - as the sole argument of a datetime arithmetic operation
> - in some cases as the sole argument of a scalar function
> - as a sort key in an ORDER BY clause
>
> Parameter markers can never be used:
>
> - in a statement that is not a prepared statement
> - in the fullselect of a CREATE VIEW statement
> - in the triggered action of a CREATE TRIGGER statement
> - in a query captured by DB2 Query Patroller
>
> The statement cannot be processed.
>
> #### User Response:
>
> Correct the syntax of the statement. If untyped parameter markers are not allowed, use the CAST specification to give the parameter marker a data type.
>
> #### sqlcode: -418
>
> #### sqlstate: 42610

Unfortunately this doesn't answer your problem since your SQL seem to look fine. After [Googling](http://www.google.com/search?q=sqlstate+42610+insert+into+select) a bit more it look more like that the DB2 JDBC driver simply doesn't eat `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` statements in a `PreparedStatement`. It's unclear if that is missing in the SQL Message Reference or a bug in the JDBC driver.